# How to determine a basis for the tangent space given a local trivialization.

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold, tangent-spaces

I heard the following:

> For a smooth submanifold $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$,
> given a local trivialization one can easily find a basis for
> the tangent space.

I want to know how.
So first I should maybe formalize the question:
Suppose $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth $k$-dimensional submanifold and for $p \in M$,$\phi:U \rightarrow V$ a local trivialization of $M$ such that $x \in M \cap U$. Then there exist functions $b_1,...,b_k$ such that $B=\{b_1(x),...,b_k(x)\}$ form a basis of $T_xM$.

My idea:
If $\phi:U \rightarrow V$ is a local trivialization, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \phi(x)_{|x=p},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\phi(x)_{|x=p}$ should be a basis for the tangent space $T_pM$.
My problems at the moment: I don't know how to explicitly show my assumption. I.e. I need to show that for $v \in T_pM$, $v$ can be written as a linear combination of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \phi(x)_{|x=p},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\phi(x)_{|x=p}$. And I also need to show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \phi(x)_{|x=p},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\phi(x)_{|x=p}$ are linearly independent.

Question: How do I show above-mentioned? Does my idea work or am I wrong?

**Edit:**

I wanted to add the Definitions I use:
Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. $M$ is a smooth $k$-dimensional submanifold if for each $x \in M$, there exists open subsets $U,V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ were $x \in U$ and there exists a diffeomorphism $\phi:U\rightarrow V$ such that $\phi(U \cap M) = V \cap \mathbb{R}^k$. I call $\phi$ a local trivialization. As far as I know, $\phi$ is sometimes also called a local parametrization.

I want to show that there exist local coordinates $b_1(x),...,b_k(x)$ of the tangent space $T_xM$.

Comment: What's your definition of tangent space?

Comment: @BenSteffan For a smooth submanifold $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $T_xM:=\{\alpha'(0):\alpha0)=x\}$, where $\alpha $is a curve from $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ to $M$.

Comment: By local trivialization, do you mean local coordinates?

Comment: @Deane No. Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. $M$ is a smooth $k$-dimensional submanifold if for each $x \in M$, there exists open subsets $U,V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ were $x \in U$ and there exists a diffeomorphism $\phi:U\rightarrow V$ such that $\phi(U \cap M) = V \cap \mathbb{R}^k$. I call $\phi$ a local trivialization. As far as I know, $\phi$ is sometimes called a local parametrization.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now it all makes sense. The confusion is because the term local trivialization is normally used to mean something else. Anyway, you get a basis of $T_pM$ from the partial derivatives of $\phi^{-1}$, not $\phi$. Observe that for each $1\le j\le k$, if you hold all but the $j$-th coordinate fixed and set $x^j=t$, that coordinate curve lies in $M$ and therefore its velocity vector is tangent to $M$. Linear independence can be proved from the fact that $\phi^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @Deane I did try to write it down: Let $v \in T_pM$, then v can be written as $v=\lambda_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \phi^{-1}(p)+...+\lambda_k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \phi^{-1}(p)$.

Let $\alpha(t):\mathbb{I}\subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$, $\alpha(t)=(\alpha_1(t),...,\alpha_k(t))$. Then $\phi^{-1}(\alpha(t)) I \rightarrow M$.

Comment: We know that $v$ is of the form $\frac{d}{dx} \phi^{-1}(\alpha(x))_{|x=0}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \phi^{-1}(\alpha(0)) \cdot \alpha_1'(0)+...\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \phi^{-1}(\alpha(0)) \cdot \alpha_k'(0)$. Since $\alpha(0)=p$, we get that $v$ is a linear combination of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \phi^{-1}(p)$.

If $0=\lambda_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \phi^{-1}(p)+...+\lambda_k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \phi^{-1}(p)$. , Then becuase $\phi^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism, its differential is injective, thus the columns of the matrix are linearly independent.

Comment: Thus $\lambda_1=...=\lambda_k=0$.

Comment: Could you tell me if this looks correct?

Answer (score 3):

You are making things appear more complicated than they are by combining two separate issues: the embedding in Euclidean space and the question of local trivialisation.  It is preferable to think of $M$ as a $k$-dimensional differentiable manifold.  Then the existence of a local chart means that one has a map $\psi$ between a neighborhood in $M$ and a neighborhood in $\mathbb R^k$.  If $(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ are the coordinates in $\mathbb R^k$, then $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}, \ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k})$ is a basis for the tangent space of $\mathbb R^k$ at a point, and their image under $d\phi$ (or its inverse) will give a basis for the tangent space to $M$ at the corresponding point.